# Are $L$ and $M$ linear transformations?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I want to determine whether the following transformations are linear:

$$L:\mathcal C^1(\Bbb R) \rightarrow \Bbb R, g \mapsto g'(0)-g(0)$$

$$M:\mathcal C^1(\Bbb R) \rightarrow \mathcal C^0(\Bbb R), g \mapsto g'-g$$

In order for a transformation to be linear it needs to satisfy the following two criteria:

> 1. $T(\lambda v)=\lambda T(v)$
> 2. $T(v+w)=T(v)+T(w)$

This is what I have done so far:

I tried to check the criteria for the transformation $L$:

$$L(\lambda g)=\lambda g'(0)-\lambda g(0)=\lambda(g'(0)-g(0))=\lambda L(g) \checkmark$$

$$L(a+b)=?$$

How do I check the second criterion?

Is the information that the function is differentiable and the derivative is continuous ($\mathcal C^1)$ important here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align} L(f+g) &= (f+g)'(0) - (f+g)(0) \\ &= (f'+g')(0) - (f+g)(0) \\ &= f'(0)+g'(0) - f(0)-g(0) \\ &= f'(0) - f(0) + g'(0) - g(0) \\ &= L(f) + L(g) \quad \checkmark\end{align}$$

> Is the information that the function is differentiable and the derivative is continuous (C1) important here?

Not relevant to the computations. This is just to make sure that $f'$ really does exist.

---

Follow your nose and use the definition: $$f \in \ker L \iff L(f) = 0 \iff f'(0) - f(0) = 0 \iff f'(0) = f(0),$$ so: $$\ker L = \{ f \in {\cal C}^1(\Bbb R) \mid f'(0) = f(0) \}.$$ On the other hand, $L$ is clearly surjective. Take $b \in \Bbb R$ and put $f(x) = b + 2bx$. So $L(f) = f'(0)-f(0) = 2b - b = b$ and $f \in {\cal C}^1(\Bbb R)$. Think alike for $M$.

---

I claim that $M$ is surjective. That is, given a continuous function $f \in {\cal C}^0(\Bbb R)$, I want $g \in {\cal C}^1(\Bbb R)$ such that: $$M(g) = g'-g = f.$$ We use an integrating factor: $$g'(x)-g(x) = f(x) \implies e^{-x}g'(x)-e^{-x}f(x) = e^{-x}f(x) \implies \frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x}(e^{-x}g(x)) = e^{-x}f(x),$$ so $$g(x) = e^x \int e^{-x}f(x)\,{\rm d}x$$ does the job (I took the constant of integration being $0$, we actually have infinite $g$ satisfying $M(g) = f$).

---

Consider $\pi: \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3$ given by $\pi(x,y,z) = (x,y,0)$. Recall the rank-nullity theorem: $$3 = \dim \ker \pi + \dim {\rm Im}\,\pi.$$ Look at $\Bbb R^2 \hookrightarrow \Bbb R^3$ in the obvious way, and let $\Bbb R{\bf e}_3$ be the $z$ axis. We have that $\Bbb R{\bf e}_3 \subset \ker \pi$, and also $\Bbb R^2 \subset {\rm Im}\,\pi$. From this $1 \leq \dim \ker \pi$ and $2 \leq \dim {\rm Im}\,\pi$. From the rank-nullity theorem we get: $$\dim \ker \pi = 1 \quad \dim{\rm Im}\,\pi,$$ so by finite-dimensionality we get: $$\ker \pi = \Bbb R{\bf e}_3 \quad {\rm Im}\,\pi = \Bbb R^2.$$

Comment: That was really quick!! Thanks. So all the criteria are satisfied and the transformation is linear. How would I go about finding the kernel and the image? I know how to do it when I have a matrix but I have no idea how to find it give this linear transformation

Comment: @Suh I added some details in the answer.

Comment: My god. You are like a machine. How do you figure this stuff out so quickly? :D. Thank you very much.

Comment: Let's say I like linear algebra a lot and let's keep it at that haha!

All ok with the exercise now?

Comment: Yeah. I will try to figure out $M$ using the information you and Rory have given me. If I am having difficulties can I comment on your post again?

Comment: Yes, sure. For $\ker M$ you'll solve a pretty easy ODE... :)

Comment: Cool! I will try my best. It might take me a while because I am really new to this stuff. But I guess practice makes perfect.

Comment: That's the spirit! Good studies.

Comment: Sorry but I have to bother you one last time :). For $M$ I verified that it is in fact a linear transformation because both criteria are satisfied. For the kernel I get $ker(M)=g'-g=0 \iff g'=g$. The general solution to this differential equation is $ce^x$. Therefore $ker(L)=${$ce^x$}. However, I am not sure how to find the image. As far as I know the image is the the subspace of the co-domain that the transformation "actually" maps to. Is there some general way to determine this because I don't see it when just looking at the transformation.

Comment: All correct. Good job. I completed the answer now.

Comment: This is awesome! I can't thank you enough. Have a nice day.

Comment: Just out of curiosity. I am guessing not every transformation is going to be surjective. What happens in that case? That just means my image is not the whole of my co-domain right? How do I figure out what part of my co-domain the transformation actually maps to?

Comment: For transformations between finite dimensional spaces, injectivity is equivalent to surjectivity. Note that for $M$, we have $\ker M \neq \{0\}$ and $M$ is surjective - this is because the ${\cal C}^k(\Bbb R)$ spaces all have infinite dimensions. For getting examples, we can think of non-injective transformations between finite dimensional spaces, such as the orthogonal projection in a plane, in $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: @Suh I added an easy example in the answer.

Comment: The example is great! Thanks for putting so much effort into this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some basic facts that quickly tell you if your two transformations are linear. You could prove these facts: it is easy. All these assume that the operator always gives a result, which is true for the domain given in your problem. That's why that domain is stated in the problem!

- The derivative transformation is linear.
- The transformation that evaluates a function at a certain point (such as $g(x)\mapsto g(0)$) is linear.
- A linear combination of linear transformations is linear.
- The composition of linear transformations is linear.

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean when you say " All these assume that the operator always gives a result, which is true for the domain given in your problem. " Which operator are you referring to? The derivative operator?

Comment: @SuH: I was referring to the derivative operator (the functions must be differentiable) and the evaluation-at-a-point operator (the function must be defined at that point). The domain $\mathcal C^1(\Bbb R)$ takes care of both of those and their composition as in $L$.

Comment: That makes a ton of sense. Thanks!